# How to get User's email in spring boot controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory

I am implementing REST APIs in Spring Boot Application which authenticates Authorization token received in Http Requests.

I have tried to get username from Principal in REstController class

Tried

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/Policies", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Policies>> getPolicy(Principal principal) {
    System.out.println("Prnicipal: " + principal.getName());        
}
```

Getting output:

```
com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad.UserPrincipal@120e283f
```

How to get User name/email ?

I am using Azure active directory dependency for authorization in **pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How can that be the output of your code? It should start with "Prnicipal: "

Comment: I am using azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter for authorization. None of the given solutions in other links are working.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using azure-spring-boot. Their [UserPrincipal](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/blob/2e01e17c7ca0f9c815d4e44c6a54a3b57af4fc1d/azure-spring-boot/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/spring/autoconfigure/aad/UserPrincipal.java) (which you see printed), does not implement java.security.principal.

Looking into their samples, I found [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/blob/99174e518cc0e5a4551ee521b97155eefdae9c0a/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-active-directory-spring-boot-sample/src/main/java/sample/aad/controller/TodolistController.java):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/todolist/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteTodoItem(@PathVariable("id") int id,
                                                 PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken authToken) {
    final UserPrincipal current = (UserPrincipal) authToken.getPrincipal();

    if (current.isMemberOf(
        new UserGroup("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", "group1"))) {
        final List<TodoItem> find = todoList.stream().filter(i -> i.getID() == id).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (!find.isEmpty()) {
            todoList.remove(todoList.indexOf(find.get(0)));
            return new ResponseEntity<>("OK", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Entity not found", HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Access is denied", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

You can see that they actually extract the principal from the PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken and cast it to UserPrincipal. Once you have a UserPrincipal instance you can access all the information present in the token. I guess you can get the name with getSubject().

For your case, I think something like this would work, although I didn't take the time to try it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/Policies", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Policies>> getPolicy(Authentication authentication) {
    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
    System.out.println("Principal: " + userPrincipal.getSubject());
```

> Update in post to get required username and email.

```
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map = (Map<String, Object>) userPrincipal.getClaims();

    System.out.println("Username: " + map.get("name"));
    System.out.println("Email: " + map.get("upn"));

}
```

Comment: @Pedro userPrincipal.getSubject() does not return required user info.

Comment: I'd say the key of the solution was using Authentication instead of Principal and casting to UserPrincipal. You could have just edited my answer...

Comment: Updated your post for getting username and email properties from user principal.

Answer (score 1):

I get the correct answer to the problem from @Pedro 's post as reference.

**SOLUTION**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/Policies", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Policies>> getPolicy(Authentication authentication) {

    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map = (Map<String, Object>) userPrincipal.getClaims();

    System.out.println("Username: " + map.get("name"));
    System.out.println("Email: " + map.get("upn"));

}
```